I have recently been receiving the '-eras' error while installing the Python packages in the VS Code terminal
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -eras (c:\users\krishna\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -eras (c:\users\krishna\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -eras (c:\users\krishna\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages)

By receiving the error i cant be able to install the packages properly. What can i do for this. Help me guys:-(
I tried by clearing the caches pip cache purge
using this command given by chatgpt.Help me to solve this issue.
